# Push nuget package only if the package version matches the Tag on Git's master branch

Tags: bash, git, nuget, nuget-package

In our development environment, we have set up a NuGet local server (BaGet). We have adopted the Gitflow idea. When a library is ready to be released on Baget, the developer should first increase the Tag on the `master` branch (which needs to be approved first via a pull-request), then push the library to the Baget. We do this to keep the version of `Git` and `Nuget` in sync.

The process of keeping versions in sync (Git tag & NuGet version) is controlled manually by the developer and sometimes some team members forget to define the Git version tag and just push the library to Baget.

It would be a great help if the `script` could check the **Current Git Tag** before pushing the library to the Baget server, and only push it if the **Tag** and **Version** are the same. This can prevent pushing a version without matching Tag on git.

We use this script for pushing to Baget:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
cd $DIR
ostype=`uname`

KEY=$NUGET_KEY
SOURCE=$NUGET_URL

while :
do
        clear
        echo "Input your package version: "
        read version
        Common="Dayan.Common/bin/Debug/Dayan.Common."$version".nupkg"        
        dotnet nuget push $Common -s $SOURCE -k $KEY
        echo "press enter to continue ..."
        read
done
```

Can I somehow check use git commands in the bash to get the Tag of the last commit on the master branch of the project, and check it with the user input for version?

Comment: Btw.: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make that check would be to use the `git` command `rev-list`.

This command will output the commit SHA of the most recent commit:

```
$ git rev-list -n 1 HEAD
dfe4a9989b33e97f25645d79fd62900cc3209ec7
```

While this command will output the commit SHA of the tag `3.1.5`:

```
$ git rev-list -n 1 "3.1.5"
a35117a201290b63b53ba6372dbf8bbfc68f28b9
```

The following example script should get you started:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Input your package version: "
read version

last_commit=$(git rev-list -n 1 HEAD 2>/dev/null)
last_commit_result=$?
if [ "$last_commit_result" != "0" ]; then
    echo "Failed to get the SHA of the most recent commit"
    exit 1
fi

version_commit=$(git rev-list -n 1 "$version" 2>/dev/null)
version_commit_result=$?
if [ "$version_commit_result" != "0" ]; then
    echo "There is no commit with the tag: $version"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$last_commit" = "$version_commit" ]; then
    echo "The most recent commit has the tag: $version"
else
    echo "The most recent commit does NOT have the tag: $version"
fi
```

If you also want to make sure the script is only run from `master` then add this near the script's start:

```bash
active_branch=$(git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null)
active_branch_result=$?
if [ "$active_branch_result" != "0" ]; then
    echo "Failed to get the active branch"
    exit 1
elif [ "$active_branch" != "master" ]; then
    echo "The active branch is not master"
    exit 1
fi
```